# C# Remove content within html tags(no regex)

Tags: c#

I want to remove the text between html tags and then display it in textBox2.
I need to get the start postion for "<" and ">"  and then delete the tags and everything in between.
I dont want to use regex.

Here's what i got so far

```
        string input = textBox1.Text;
        string output = textBox2.Text;
        string results;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if(input.IndexOf('<',i) !=-1 )
            {


            }
```

Comment: Can `<` and `>` appear more than once? Do you want to handle cases where `<` and `>` can appear inside each other? Are they guaranteed to appear in the string? Can the input be malformed so that a `<` can exist without a `>`?

Comment: Input is a textbox so lets say the user inputs: Hi <backround="blue"> Benny, the output would be Hi Benny.

Comment: @Dan Herbert Yes, they can appear more than once, but they cant appear within eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for. However, it won't handle cases where there is malformed markup. So for example, if you were to enter the input string `Hello < world`, the output would be `Hello`.

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
bool inATag = false;

for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
    if (!inATag && input[i] != '>' && input[i] != '<') {
        output.Append(input[i]);
    } else if (input[i] == '<') {
        inATag = true;
    } else if (input[i] == '>') {
        inATag = false;
    }
}

textBox2.Text = output.ToString();
```

To explain a little more about what's going on, I'm iterating through the input string one character at a time. If I find an opening `<`, I enter a state where I will not add any of the input to the output until I find the closing `>`.

The way I'm generating the output string is by using a `StringBuilder` to do string concatenation, which improves performance over using just `string output += input[i]`. It is not recommended to simply use a `string` as your output variable type because every time you concatenate 2 strings together, it allocates a completely new and distinct string. Over time, this will impact performance. With a `StringBuilder`, only one string object will be allocated, and no new string objects are created with every iteration through the loop.

Microsoft has [written a good explanation of why to use a `StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but the general rule is that you should be using a StringBuilder any time you find yourself concatenating strings inside of a loop.

Conversely, for situations where your input string is known to always be small, [it is better to **not** use a `StringBuilder`](http://improvingsoftware.com/2011/02/11/concatenating-strings-youre-still-doing-it-wrong/). There is a penalty for creating a `StringBuilder` object that isn't overcome if you're only concatenating a small number of strings. For example, if you expect to only do 10 string concatenations it would be considered an anti-pattern to use a StringBuilder. However if you're concatenating hundreds of strings, like you are in this example, it is a *very* good candidate for using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: `output.Append(input[i]);`

Comment: @A.V Thanks. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @DanHerbert Can you explain your code? What does output.Append(input[i]); do? And why do we have to use string builder ?

Comment: @Benny I've added an explanation to my code. If anything else is unclear, let me know and I'll update my answer.